# Wrong origin coordinates logic for polygon

Tags: java, libgdx

what i have now in test project, where i try to fix this problem:

2 polygon objects

2 actors, each of actor contain one polygon object

1 array with actors, i run through it in render method and with use of shapeRenderer draw polygons

1 OrthographicCamera

1 Stage

1 ScreenViewport

The logic is next: i create polygon 1 and polygon 2 with the same size and same position at 0,0 .

Than i do setPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2). Than i translate one polygon by 50 pixel on axis X and run setOrigin(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2). And i added InputListener for first polygon, when i click on it i do rotateBy on second actor with second polygon. My camera has Y-Up. On rotation second polygon think that his origin point is top right corner of the screen and do rotation around it.

Here is and gif of result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvaI5.gif

And scheme how it behave: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdM7Q.jpg

And here is gif of its behave if i maximize window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXWp6.gif . Here we can see that after resize, green polygon do rotation around the point which was before resize top right cornern of the screen.

Here is a test project with this problem https://www.dropbox.com/s/ti2iiwm2cbom62f/polygonRotation.zip?dl=0

Could anyone help to find out where is a problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you misuse the `setOrigin` method. In your code in `PolygonRotation.java`:

```
public void create () {
  float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
  float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

  //...

  p1.setVertices(getVertices(0, 0, 20, 5));
  p2.setVertices(getVertices(0, 0, 20, 5));

  pActor pa1 = new pActor();
  pActor pa2 = new pActor();

  actors.add(pa1);
  actors.add(pa2);

  //...

  pa1.setPosition(w/2, h/2);

  //...

  pa2.setPosition(pa1.getX(), pa1.getY());

  //...

  pa2.setOrigin(pa1.getX(), pa1.getY()); // <-- This line

  //...

  drawViewportBox(w, h);
}
```

Origin is not the coordinates of polygon's center, but is rather the offset from it.

According to your code both polygons are positioned into center of the screen (`w/2`, `h/2`).

Then you set origin of `w/2`, `h/2` for second polygon which sums up with it's current position and equals to `w` and `h`. In other words origin is set to the right upper corner of the screen, which is clearly the case.

Comment: seems logical, i added next changes in code: in my actor method setPosition i added next line at the end setOrigin(oldOriginX-(x-oldX), oldOriginY-(y-oldY)); and in moveBy of my actor i added to the end next line setOrigin(-x, -y); . And the result is actually is what i needed: [ImGur](http://i.imgur.com/jaYR0n4.gifv)

Answer (score 1):

Both your camera and your first polygon are in the position **(0,0)**.

Your camera is the same size as your screen. So:

```
setOrigin(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2);
```

sets the point to the top right corner of it.

If you want the point to be in the middle, then set it like this:

```
setOrigin(0, 0);
```

Alternatively, you can keep the origin point and just move the camera instead. So the world origin is in the Bottom Left corner of it.

```
camera.position.set(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2, Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2);
```

[image]

Comment: camera in my code has coordinate at left bottom corner(it is even wrote in API doc for OrthographicCamera [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera)). User CodingHamster mentioned that i need to use not exactly coordinate point but offset to that point from origin 0,0 and seems that idea has sense.